# rails 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 11 (Psych::SyntaxError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I have successfully installed rails 4 and created project using rails 4.0.0

```
rails s
```

for the first time was working fine. But after adding 'devise' gem in gemfile

```
 gem 'devise', '~> 3.0.0.rc'
```

and running bundle install, I am getting following error. What is the cause of this error and what will be the solution for it?

I have tried with commenting gem 'devise' section also, but now i am getting same error for every rails command.

```
/home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse':   (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 11 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:318:in `load_file'
from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:191:in `initialize'
from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `new'
from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `do_configuration'
from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
```

database.yml file

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
database: realstate_development
pool: 5
username: root
password: root
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

gem 'devise' with any version, is showing following error on bundle, if I remove devise gem it works fine, I used rails 3.2.13 but I never faced such problem, what a strange.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 11 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:318:in `load_file'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:191:in `initialize'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:319:in `new'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:319:in `configuration'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:34:in `configuration'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:53:in `sources='
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:250:in `remote_specs'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:163:in `fetch_specs'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:67:in `specs'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `each'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `block in index'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `index'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/siv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: could you please post also your database.yml file?

Comment: people usually post additional files by editing

Comment: bundle install also raised same error with this error message:              Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!  And I followed http://bit.ly/bundler-issues but no solution.

Comment: The problem is in one (or more) yaml file, probably in database.yml in your project if exception is raised by Psych gem.

Comment: are you sure all the settings for each environment indented to follow yaml syntax?

Comment: @SaidTalantbekov: You were right. Thanks so much. I just did: rvm pkg install libyaml and rvm reinstall all --force. It works fine for me. Which devise version you suggest me to use in rails 4.0.0.

Comment: Definitely < 3.0 version, as this version completely drops support for Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.8.7, only keeping compatibility with both Rails 3.2 and Rails 4, running with Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0 [link](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/devise-and-rails-4/)

Answer (score 9):

If somebody still comes the same error you may to check the **YAML** files in your project. In this example the problem is missed indentations in **database.yml**. It should looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: realstate_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I get the same error but on other grounds, and the whole problem was in incorrect **application.yml**

Comment: For me, the problem was having a malformed string in my YAMl.  I had `host: local:` when I needed to have `host: local`.  Hope this helps anyone else with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

First note the yml file in which parse method fails due to Psych::SyntaxError. Then look the file for the following

The YAML files should be properly indented and correct syntax must be followed. 
**1.All members of a list are lines beginning at the same indentation level starting with a "- " (a dash and a space):**
**2.A dictionary is represented in a simple key: value form (the colon must be followed by a space):**
For more syntax related information check the following link: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html