# bundle install results in "mapping values are not allowed in this context" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, yaml, bundler

I have a rails 4 project that has been working for some time. I attempted to install  `taps` but got an error message:

```
$ gem install taps

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 29 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:333:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I get the same error message when trying to run `gem list` or `bundle update`. I [searched for similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685702/rails-4-mapping-values-are-not-allowed-in-this-context-at-line-2-column-11-psy), and it seems the cause is typically an improperly formatted YAML file. My `database.yml` file and `Gemfile` were not recently updated, so I don't know when this bug was introduced.

I found a [rails issue on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8143) that describes this error, and someone recommended parsing YAML files with `irb` to isolate the issue. I tried parsing `database.yml` and `Gemfile`:

**config/database.yml**

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

```
$ irb -ryaml
2.2.1 :001 > YAML.load_file 'config/database.yml'
 => {"default"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}, "development"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/development.sqlite3"}, "test"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/test.sqlite3"}, "production"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/production.sqlite3"}}
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.2'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'devise',                  '3.5.6'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

```
$ irb -ryaml
2.2.1 :001 > YAML.load_file 'Gemfile'
 => "source 'https://rubygems.org'\n\ngem 'rails',                   '4.2.2' gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2' gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7' gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10' gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0' gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2' gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3' gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0' gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3' gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0' gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3' gem 'devise',                  '3.5.6'\ngroup :development, :test do gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9' gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0' gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3' gem 'spring',      '1.1.3' end\ngroup :test do gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5' gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3' gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1' end\ngroup :production do gem 'pg',             '0.17.1' gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2' end"
```

Both files parse correctly, so I am stuck. I don't know why the commands keep failing since the error message doesn't identify the offending file.

Comment: not sure re: your problem...but are you sure you want to use that taps gem at all? It doesn't appear to be actively maintained. No one has committed anything to it in years and there are tons of open issues. I would uninstall that gem and go down a different path.

Comment: I ran my program in the development environment (sqlite) with production data for a while. Now that I am ready to move to production on Heroku (postgresql), I would like to migrate the existing data from sqlite to postgresql. It seemed like taps was the easiest way, but I would of course be open to a better method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to track down the source of this error.

**rubygems/config_file.rb:**

```
SYSTEM_WIDE_CONFIG_FILE = File.join SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH, 'gemrc'
...
system_config = load_file SYSTEM_WIDE_CONFIG_FILE
```

I tried parsing my .gemrc file and it failed:

```
$ irb -ryaml
2.2.1 :001 > YAML.load_file '/home/ubuntu/.gemrc'
Psych::SyntaxError: (/home/ubuntu/.gemrc): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 29
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:464:in `block in load_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:464:in `open'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:464:in `load_file'
        from (irb):1
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Somehow, two lines became joined in my **~/.gemrc:**

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri
update: --no-rdoc --no-rigem: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Separating them back out resolved the problem:

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri
update: --no-rdoc --no-ri
gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Since my .gemrc file is not under my project's revision control, I was seeing the error no matter which historical commit I checked out.