# Error when starting server locally: "could not find expected ':'" , Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I was trying to set up my app on heroku. Before that, I could type `rails s` to start the server and everything went flawless.

Then (maybe unrelated to my actual problem), I added `config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` to my `config/evironments/production.rb` file and pushed it to github and after that, to heroku. The app on heroku works.

After that, whenever I type rails s, this happens:

```
mycomp:~/workspace/philosophica$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `rescue in database_configuration': YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 24 column 1 (RuntimeError)
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:98:in `database_configuration'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /home/sandro/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/sandro/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I noticed this:

```
YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 24 column 1 (RuntimeError)
```

Here is how my database.yml looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: a_number
  host: localhost    #line 21
  username: name     #line 22
  password: password #line 23
                     #line 24
```

It mentions an error at line 24, but line 24 is empty. At this point, I'm clueless. Has anyone any advises? Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: My default seems to come first, here my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: name
  password: pasword



development:
  <<: *default
  database: philosophica_development
```

Edit 2: When I type in `rake routes` this happens:

```
rake aborted!
YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 24 column 1
/home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 24 column 1
(erb):87:in `<main>'
/home/sandro/workspace/philosophica/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
```

My `config/environment.rb` looks like this:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!  #line 5
```

Maybe this is helpful

Edit 3: Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby File.read('.ruby-version').strip

gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'pg_search'

gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.0.2', require: 'mailgun'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'tinymce-rails'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'rake', '~> 11.1.2'
gem 'simple_form'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'gon'
gem 'sprockets'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Edit 4: @Rewritten: You mean like this? If so, I still have the same error

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: philosophica_development

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: name
  password: password
```

Comment: do u have sqlite gem in gemfile ?

Comment: @ 7urkm3n I'm using postgresql as database and I have therefore a pg gem in gemfile.

Comment: in both `dev` and `production` ?

Comment: @7urkm3n I believe so: I added my gemfile and gem pg should be in both, if I understand my gemfile correctly

Comment: Have you tried putting all YAML values in quotes (e.g. `etc: "value"`)?

Comment: @HalilÖzgür I added quotes to every value but I still get the same error. Maybe, it sounds crazy, but the error seems to be the same, no matter what I do. It seems like, I'm not working on the right file, but why did it work before?

Comment: @Metaphysiker well it was more of a last resort suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the syntax error is in an other referenced yml file in the project (e.g secrets.yml).

It seems that errors in secrets.yml are reported as errors in database.yml.

Comment: Please provide some explanation and references to support your answer

Comment: it seems that errors in secrets.yml are reported as errors in database.yml.

I did not yet have time to debug the reason behind this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your `default` block is down in the file. YAML is not able to look for forward references, so the `&default` marker MUST come before its corresponding `<<: *default` insertion point(s).

```
# not working
development:
  <<: *default

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
```

instead of

```
# working
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql

development:
  <<: *default
```

Comment: I added a part of my database.yml. My default seems to come first. Any more suggetions?

Comment: Please read the post a second time... Switch your two bloc of code, as said. Your default has to be on second place.

Comment: @Destrif is your comment for me or for th OP?

Comment: @Destrif I switched the two blocks of code (you can see it under edit 4), and I get the same error. Did you mean this?

Comment: your file database.yaml looks fine, if you have no tabs in it. verify you config/environment.rb file or remove your .gemrc from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920892/bundle-install-results-in-mapping-values-are-not-allowed-in-this-context-error
Feel free to upvote if it helped :)

Comment: @Destrif Thanks for the link! Can you help me a bit more? I can't find the .gemrc file. I googled it, but I couldn't find any help there. How do I remove that gemrc file?

Comment: Thanks! I found it and deleted it, but I still got the same error. Can you specify, what you mean, with verifying my config/environment.rb?

Comment: Remove the `ruby File.read('.ruby-version').strip` line from your gemfile. And the order of the YAML was ok, the `&` before the `<<: *`.

Comment: I removed it and after that, I run "rails s" and the same error appears. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Metaphysiker can you paste your whole `database.yml` on pastebin or gist or similar? pasting here won't show tab issues. (just clean it up from private data and ensure it still fails).

Comment: @rewritten Another user suggested, that the error on line 24 does not refer to the database.yml but to a referenced yml and mentioned as an example the secrets.yml. There, I found a misplaced ' which caused the problem

Answer (score 1):

Please check if in this empty line there are no blank characters like 'tab' because:

> Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. **Tabs are not allowed**.

Comment: I checked, there are no blank characters. The weird thing is, that I haven't changed database.yml and before the deployment to heroku, it worked fine. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the password, maybe you are using some invalid character that affects the parsing

Comment: I changed my password, but the same error still happens. The weird thing is, that I haven't changed my database.yml during my deployment for heroku. Any more ideas?